# In Bash, is it possible to distinguish a process exiting with a status > 128 from a signal?

Tags: bash

The Bash shell will set the `$?` parameter to `(128 + signal number)` when a command is killed by a signal. However, a command may call `exit()` with an argument larger than 128, without being killed by a signal. How can I distinguish the two cases, short of writing a wrapper that executes the original program and uses `wait(2)` to inspect the exit status?

In other words, how can I recover the full 8 bits of the exit status used by the command?

Comment: Exit statuses greater than 128 are *reserved* (by POSIX, anyway) as indicating the command exited due to a signal. A program shouldn't be using them for their own purposes.

Comment: (See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_21_18.)

Comment: @chepner To be honest, I'm not reading the POSIX document as if programs aren't supposed to be using exit statuses > 128 - just that the shell will report them in a way that's indistinguishable from a fatal signal. I agree it's probably not a good idea to be using exit statuses > 128, but in my case I am stuck with specifications that I cannot influence.

Comment: That link didn't work as I expected. The text I am reading is in the Rationale section for the `exit` special built-in: "RATIONALE
As explained in other sections, *certain exit status values have been reserved for special uses and should be used by applications only for those purposes:*

[...]
 >128
A command was interrupted by a signal." To me, that says an exit status of 129 should always indicate the application was killed by signal 1, rather than indicating an application-specific error.